# Input Box Text Grouping Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to write a a block style input text box. I realized I might not be describing it correctly and if someone could give me the proper name, I would appreciate it. Basically I want the functionality of how GMail uses their email address client:

[image]

I don't need the autocorrect functionality, just the part where a user presses the enter key and it places it in a single entity/block and you can continue to type.

I'm sure there are libraries out there but I've had trouble finding them since I don't know what the technical name for them are. Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Just to clarify for everyone else, its the "Automatic tokenization" section of the page. If you could answer this question with the code of the "Automatic tokenization" section, I will mark it as best answer. Thanks!